Plaster walls and painting/primer
I have old plaster walls, that have previously been painted. I started painting a new color (oil based paint for the plaster), and totally spaced priming the walls first! Can I just put primer over what I painted, and then put the new color on? Do I need to strip the pain off? The walls are textured, so stripped off the paint sounds like a MAJOR pain!

If the new paint you applied is adhering well and giving you the correct color, keep painting.
Primer is for when a color may bleed through ( like painting white over red) or when a wall is fresh drywall or plaster, or over a repair. Also needed if the sheen is glossy and a base is needed for new paint to "grip".
Painting a new color over the old without primer is done often with good results.
